# VBA fix .Text .Replace in code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The code below opens a word doc (working) then i want to find and replace the text my prog is crashing with a '438' error, "Object Doesn't support this property or method"! Cheers  !

```
Sub OpenWordFile()
        Dim objWord as Object

      Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      objWord.Visible = True 
      objWord.Documents.Open "C:\..."
      With objWord.Find
      .Text = "aaa"
      .Replacement.Text = "bbbb"
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Down voted, for lack of information regarding where the error occurs..

Comment: Hi @MakDo, does my answer below address your issue?

Comment: yes @leekaiinthesky it did ! thanks loads !!! that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118.aspx. `Find` is available from the `Selection` and `Range` objects. You are trying to access it from an instance of Word. You need to define a `Selection` or `Range` first and access it from there.

Take a look at the example code in the documentation, but you can do something like this (adapting the sample code for your use case), so that `myRange.Find` represents the object you're looking for:

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content 
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="aaa", ReplaceWith:="bbbb", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```